# Использование ng-template в Angular

Tags: angular2

Задача состоит в том, чтобы написать компонент table, который будет поддерживать темплейты.

Пример того, чтобы хотелось иметь:

```
<my-table>
    <table-column name="Some name"></table-column>
    <table-column name="Some name2"></table-column>
    <table-column name="Some name3">
        <ng-template let-i="item">
            <a routerLink="/someway/{{i.id}}">Link</a>
        </ng-template>
    </table-column>
</my-table>
```

Столкнулся с проблемой, что не очень понимаю, как правильно прокидывать данные в ng-template. Гугл не смог особо мне помочь с этой проблемой. Может кто подскажет, как это нужно сделать правильно или даст ссылочки на статьи, где описывается, как обыгрывать темплейты в таких сценария?

Comment: ng-template это то что внутри my-table при создании. <my-table>asdasd</my-table. И asdasd вставиться на место ng-template в коде определения.

Comment: @НазарКалитюк, я имел ввиду немного другой механизм. Хотелось бы иметь понимание того, как правильно прокидывать данные внутрь ng-template, используя *ngFor на более высоком уровне в дереве.

Comment: Можно внутри my-table написать ngFor, а потом все появиться на месте ng-template внутри описания компонента

Comment: <my-table> *ngFor... </my-table> это там где мы используем

Comment: <my-table>
    <table-column name="Some name"></table-column>
    <table-column name="Some name2"></table-column>
    <table-column name="Some name3">
        <ng-template></ng-template>
    </table-column>
</my-table> это где разметка компонета.

Comment: @НазарКалитюк для меня это не очень удобно, потому что внутри много другой логики, связанной в таблицами

Comment: на самом деле вас здесь ng-template совсем не нужен. Максиму можно написать <my-table [items]=items> чтоб передать элементы. А внутри компонента все реализовать.

Comment: Клёво. И что, для каждой таблицы писать отдельную реализацию?

Comment: Что значит для каждой? Для каждого типа да, или можно сделать одну, но с настойками чтоб разные столбцы и тд были.

Comment: @НазарКалитюк, я просто не понимаю, чем подход с использованием шаблонов, который используется многими библиотеками, плох? А когда нужно сделать select с кастомными item, тоже везде самому *ngFor везде писать?